# widget flutter to sticking to left, and right

Tags: flutter, dart, constraints

I have this widget code

```
child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Container(alignment: Alignment.topLeft, child: BtnPoin()),
      Container(alignment: Alignment.topRight, child: BtnFilter()),
    ],
  ),
```

can i put `BtnPoin()` to sticking to the left, ant `BtnFilter()` to the right
here my pic reference

[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuHR5.png)

Comment: Remove `CrossAxisAlignment.center` and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      BtnPoin(),
      BtnFilter(),
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[
             BtnPoin(),
             Spacer(),
             BtnFilter(),
    ],
  ),
```